# Updating object in array with Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How can I update an object inside an array with Vuex? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
const state = {
  categories: []
};

// mutations:
[mutationType.UPDATE_CATEGORY] (state, id, category) {
  const record = state.categories.find(element => element.id === id);
  state.categories[record] = category;
}

// actions:
updateCategory({commit}, id, category) {
  categoriesApi.updateCategory(id, category).then((response) => {
    commit(mutationType.UPDATE_CATEGORY, id, response);
    router.push({name: 'categories'});
  })
}
```

Comment: what is wrong?what error you have?

Comment: Reactivity in vue works different to what you might expect. Either pre-create the properties in the state object or use the Vue.set function - https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: Vuex Mutations and Actions can receive only two parameters, check the docs https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

Comment: Any way to update object in array using vuex ?. Using directly using axios it's great but I'm happy with state mangagement.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
[mutationType.UPDATE_CATEGORY] (state, id, category) {
  state.categories = [
     ...state.categories.filter(element => element.id !== id),
     category
  ]
}
```

This works by replacing the 'categories' array with the original array without the matching element,  and then concatenating the updated element to the end of the array.

One caveat to this method is that it destroys the order of the array, although in a lot of cases that won't be a problem. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: It replaces the existing state.categories with a new array that contains the old category-objects without the update category-object, and appends the new category object to it.

Comment: @Davіd To answer your question, the reason the above code works is because the change detection takes place when the array reference changes. Any operation using array methods would trigger change detection [Vuejs.org](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection)

Similarly adding or removing items also needs array reference update Eg: 
state.myArray[2] = {id: "112", name: "ABC"}
state.myArray = [...state.myArray]
[Ref](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/)

Comment: This is how you do it without destroying the order of array `state. categories = [...state. categories.map(item => item.id !== updatedItem.id ? item : {...item, ...updatedItem})]`

Comment: What is the advantage of creating an entirely new array (without the update object) and then appending a new object to that array vs. using finding the index and calling `splice`?