# Changing value of object in an array in vuex store by the rendered component prop

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have an array of object in vuex store.
I take this to a page and render using a components. all ok
What i want is to be able to change the value of the spesific object i use the data to render the component. I hope this makes sense. My main problem is, how can i modify the spesific object in the array

```
export const state = () => {  return {
villas: [
  {name: 'First', location:'a1', date:2014, rating:4.9}, 
  {name: 'Second', location:'a2', date:2014, rating:4.8}, 
  {name: 'Third', location:'a3', date:2014, rating:4.9}, 
  {name: 'Fourth', location:'a4', date:2014, rating:4.9}, 
  {name: 'Fourth', location:'a5', date:2014, rating:4.9}, 
  {name: 'Fourth', location:'a6', date:2014, rating:4.9}, 
  {name: 'Fourth', location:'a7', date:2014, rating:4.9}, 
  {name: 'Fifth', location:'a8', date:2014, rating:4.9}],  }}
```

my page

```
<v-layout class="go" row>
          <Gond v-for="villa in villas" :key="villa.name" :name="villa.name" :location="villa.location" :date="villa.date" :rating="villa.rating"/>
</v-layout>
```

and my component

```
  export default {
props: ['name', 'location', 'date', 'rating'],
data() {
  return {
  }
},
```

Comment: I have very big component i cant share all

Comment: In what way would you like to modify them then? I think we need more than what is currently available to properly help you.

Comment: All store modifications that you would like to do outside that store should be done by mutations and corresponding actions that you have to define in the store.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an action and a mutation to update the store data

Assuming the villa names are unique,

Create a getter(optional),

```
getVillaByName: state => {
    return state.villas.filter(villa => villa.name)
}
```

Create an action

```
updateVillaByName ({commit }, payload) {
    commit('UPDATE_VILLA_BY_NAME', payload)
}
```

Create a mutation

```
UPDATE_VILLA_BY_NAME (state, updatedVilla) {

  // there are few different ways you can update the array of objects
  // one way is to go like below. Ref - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422357/updating-object-in-array-with-vuex][1]

  state.villas = [
     ...state.villas.filter(element => element.name !== updatedVilla.name),
     updatedVilla
  ]
}
```

In your component for example,

```
methods: {
  updateVillaLocation (newLocation) {

    let villa = this.$store.getters.getVillaByName(this.name)

    villa.location = newLocation

    this.$store.commit('updateVillaByName', villa)
  }
}
```

Also instead of passing individual props, you can simply pass it as below. This way when you want to update, you can make a **copy** of the villa prop and make modifications to it and send it to store action

```
<Gond v-for="villa in villas" :key="villa.name" :villa="villa"/>
```

Hope this answers your question :) Please accept the answer if it helped and let me know if you need more guidance